# Getting different parts of a line

Tags: shell, shell-script, text-processing, scripting

Suppose I have a line of text as follows:

```
I have a nice car
```

Is there any way to get different words of the line at different positions individually (say, I want to get 'have' and 'nice' parts) without saving the line to any file. I mean, I want to apply such a method which will directly give me words at desired positions of the given line. Is there any way?

Comment: There are many ways. I advise you to get familiar with `awk`, `grep`, `sed`, `cut` and so on... And search the site (the `text-processing` tag is a good place to start).

Answer (score 6):

Use `awk` try this:

```
$ awk '{print $2, $4}' file
```

Where `$x` is the word position, this is delimited by whitespaces

e.g.

```
$ echo "I have a nice car" | awk '{print $2, $4}'
have nice
```

Answer (score 5):

bash has arrays:

```
line="I have * nice car"
set -f                      # disable pathname expansion
words=($line)               # no quotes around $line
set +f                      # re-enable pathname expansion
```

`words` is an index array, zero-based, so

```
# print the 2nd word
echo "${words[1]}"               # ==> have

# print the 2nd-last word
echo "${words[-2]}"              # ==> nice
```

Converting the string to an array splits the string at any sequence of characters contained in the shell's `$IFS` variable (default: space, tab, newline)

Comment: If you're going to use the `split+glob` operator, you should disable the `glob` part which you don't want here.

Comment: On shells without arrays, you can do `set -f; unset IFS; set -- $line` and have the words in `$1`, `$2`...

Answer (score 3):

```
line="I have a nice car"
fields=$(echo "$line" | awk '{ print $2 " " $4 }')
```

That splits by whitespace. If you want character positions instead, use `cut`.

Answer (score 1):

the `cut` option

```
echo I have a nice car | cut -d\  -f2,4
have nice
```

where

- `-d' '` tell cut to use white space instead of tab
- `-f2,4` get 2nd and 4th field

Comment: Perhaps `-d' '` would be a little clearer than `-d\ `